# How can I bulk import AD users with multi-line street addresses?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to bulk import user street addresses via CSV but when doing so the street address ends up all on a single line.

I read [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2f915bfe-2adb-4b27-9b6c-4881e7234986/creating-users-with-powershell-and-inputting-multiline-street-address-from-csv-file) to input a "`r`n" between lines but this doesn't seem to work as it just adds those characters to the street address and it doesn't actually add a line break.

This seems it should be something simple but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Note: Our domain functional level is Windows Server 2012 R2 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Try using regex to replace the invisible line break with a space?

Comment: Post what you've done so far. Whats the csv look like? Whats the powershell look like? When I run a simple test with set-aduser -streetaddress "123 Main `r`n Apt 456" it works fine. Backticks dont render properly in comments